# list is empty in spring controller when passing multiple attached files from angularjs to spring controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I am working on angularjs and spring application.
I am trying to send the attached files list to the spring controller, but in the spring controller the files are not getting listed and the size is zero.
How to send all the attached files information to the spring controller. I think i followed each and every step required to pass the files information to the spring controller, am i missing anything?

Below is the code:

html:

```
 <input type="file"  id="f" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFileDetails(this);this.value=null;" />
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="submitdata()">Send</button>
```

js:

```
myApp.controller('sendFilesController', function ($rootScope, $scope, MyService) {
    $scope.files = [];
    $scope.getFileDetails = function(e) {
        console.log("getFileDetails called");
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) {
                var isFileAvailable = false;
                console.log("File Name  " + e.files[i].name);
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.files.length; j++) {
                    if ($scope.files[j].name === e.files[i].name) {
                        isFileAvailable = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isFileAvailable) {
                    $scope.files.push(e.files[i]);
                } else {
                    alert("file is already available ::" + e.files[i].name)
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $scope.submitdata = function() {
        console.log("in submit data");
        console.log("$scope.files :: " + $scope.files );
        var data = new FormData();
        for (var i in $scope.files) {
            console.log($scope.files[i]);
            data.append("uploadFile[" + i + "]", $scope.files[i]);
        }
        MyService.sendFiles(data).then(
            function (response) {
             },
            function (errResponse) {

            }
        );
    }
    });
```

MyService.js

```
 _myservice.sendFiles = function (data) {
        console.log("in service ---" + data);
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var repUrl = appURL + '/allFilesData/filesInfo.form';
         var config = {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            transformResponse: angular.identity,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        }
        $http.post(repUrl, data, config).then(function (response) {

        }, function (response) {
         });
```

Statements shown on browser console:

```
getFileDetails called
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11629 File Name  huan.txt
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11629 File Name  plunker.txt
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11625 getFileDetails called
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11629 File Name  hi.txt
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11645 in submit data
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11646 $scope.files :: [object File],[object File],[object File]
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11649 File(577) {name: "huan.txt", lastModified: 1514928317302, lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 02 2018 16:25:17 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 577, …}
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11649 File(52) {name: "plunker.txt", lastModified: 1521206671724, lastModifiedDate: Fri Mar 16 2018 09:24:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 52, …}
chartController.js?dummy=0.23143028468115556:11649 File(2) {name: "hi.txt", lastModified: 1529336556340, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jun 18 2018 11:42:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2, …}
myService.js?dummy=0.6961916610309059:1840 in  service ---[object FormData]
```

Spring controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/filesInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String sendFiles(@RequestBody List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("In SPring controller");
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        List<Object> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for(MultipartFile file : multiPartFileList) {
            files.add(new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()));
        }
        map.put("files", files);
        System.out.println("files " + files);
    //logic
    }
```

Print statements from above controller is :

```
In Spring controller
files []
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `@Controller` should specify the `List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList` as `@RequestParam("file")`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filesInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendFiles(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList) throws Exception {
    ...
```

And your client-side `submitdata` method should be changed slightly to append files to the `FormData` object using the same `file` key for every file, as follows:

```
$scope.submitdata = function() {
  console.log("in submit data");
  console.log("$scope.files :: " + $scope.files );
  var data = new FormData();
  for (var i in $scope.files) {
    console.log($scope.files[i]);
    data.append("file", $scope.files[i]);
  }
  ...
```

FYI, I did my testing using a Spring Boot (2) application as a host running Apache Tomcat/8.5.31.

HTH

Comment: What do you want to do with these files once that you have uploaded them?

Comment: I want to send email with attachments. When user attaches multiple files it should able to send multiple files. In my spring controller code if i use only @RequestBody MultipartFile multiPartFileList as the sendFiles(..) method argument i can able to successfully send one file as attachment, but when trying to send multiple files and modified the code accordingly the spring controller could not able to get the files information and showing empty list. Any example using angularjs and spring mvc to send multiple files would be really helpful..

Comment: I updated my answer.  Please let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: I have done exactly the same way you mentioned  after i raised the question here and i could get the files information but was stuck with other issue which i have raised here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960102/how-to-pass-json-object-as-a-pathvariable-to-spring-controller?noredirect=1#comment88917583_50960102. Any inputs on this?

Comment: OK.  I will take a look at your other issue and see if I can spot anything.  By the way, if my solution worked for you can you upvote it pls?