# how to pass JSON object as a PathVariable to spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring, angular

I am working on spring application with angularjs. I want to pass the JSON object as a `@PathVariable` to the spring controller, but with my below code, when passing the JSON object as a PathVariable it is not hitting the spring controller, and it is not showing any error too.Any inputs?

sample code:
js:

```
myApp.controller('passJSONTestController', function ($rootScope, $scope, MyService) {
     $scope.submitdata=function(){
        $scope.myJSONData = [
            {   'name':$scope.name,
                'sinNumber': $scope.sinNo,
                'status': $scope.status,
                'message':$scope.message,
            }
        ];
        var fd=new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
            console.log("file " + file);
            fd.append('file',file);
        });
        MyService.sendJSON($scope.myJSONData,fd).then(
            function (response) {
                //
            },
            function (errResponse) {
             }
        );
    }
});
```

MyService.js

```
myService.sendJSON = function (myJSONData,fd) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
        var myUrl = applnURL + '/dataStack/' + myJSONData + '/getAllDataInfo.form';
          var config = {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers : {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        }
         $http.post(repUrl, fd, config ).then(function (response) {
        }, function (response) {
         });
         return deferred.promise;
     }
```

spring controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dataStack")
public class GetData {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{myJSONData}/getAllDataInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String sendInfo(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList,@PathVariable("myJSONData") List<MyDTO> myDTO){                          
        System.out.println("In Spring controller");
   }
```

Why is the request passed not hitting the spring controller?
PS: If i remove the pathvariable in spring controller and remove it from mySerivce.js, then it is hitting the spring controller.

-------------EDITED (Updated code)--------------
I have added the below class:

```
@Configuration
public class MultiFileResolverConfig {
    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        System.out.println("--In configuration file multipartResolver--");
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

spring-servlet.xml
I have added below `<bean>` in sprig-servlet.xml configuration file

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
```

html code:

```
<html>
..elements for name,sinNumber,status,message
  <input type = "file"  name="file" file-model="file" multiple/>
..//submit button
</html>
```

js code:

```
 myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

    myApp.controller('passJSONTestController', function ($rootScope, $scope, MyService) {
         $scope.submitdata=function(){
            $scope.myJSONData = [
                {   'name':$scope.name,
                    'sinNumber': $scope.sinNo,
                    'status': $scope.status,
                    'message':$scope.message,
                }
            ];
            var fd=new FormData();
            angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
                console.log("file " + file);
                fd.append('file',file);
            });
            fd.append("json",$scope.myJSONData);
            MyService.sendJSON(fd).then(
                function (response) {
                    //
                },
                function (errResponse) {
                 }
            );
        }
    });
```

service.js

```
myService.sendJSON = function (fd) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
        var myUrl = applnURL + '/dataStack/getAllDataInfo.form';
          var config = {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers : {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        }
         $http.post(myUrl, fd, config ).then(function (response) {
        }, function (response) {
         });
         return deferred.promise;
     }
```

spring controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dataStack")
public class GetDataController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllDataInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String uploadMultipleFileHandler(MultipartHttpServletRequest req) {

        System.out.println("in spring upload multiple files");
        List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList = req.getFiles("file");
        System.out.println("in multiPartFileList " + multiPartFileList.size());//size is always zero
        String[] json = (String[]) req.getParameterMap().get("json");//getting the values submitted
        //code here..
```

I am getting the values for json object but unable to get the files details.
The size of multiPartFileList.size() is zero.I tried adding only class MultiFileResolverConfig and removing the `<bean>` declaration in spring-servlet.xml but still the file details is not been passed to the spring controller.

Comment: Why you passing through json object with variable, you should go for @RequestParam or the best approach is using POST and pass through requestbody

Comment: I tried using post and passing through RequestBody, if you see my post method in above code iam passing url,fd,config information and when I added this Json object as other argument and modified spring controller to accept RequestBody it is still not recognizing the spring controller ...

Comment: You have to change the request mapping url too.

Answer (score 1):

> Update 06/22/2018

When it comes to multipart requests note that Spring Boot and Spring MVC work differently.  By default Spring MVC does *not* provide a MultipartResolver and therefore cannot resolve multipart requests.  You have to provide a "multipartResolver" bean in your ApplicationContext.  However, Spring MVC does provide two implementations for this; `StandardServletMultipartResolver` and `CommonsMultipartResolver`.  Configuring either of these into your application context will work.  For example:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {
   @Bean
   public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
      return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
   }
}
```

NB: the name of the bean is important.

On the other hand Spring Boot will autoconfigure an instance of `StandardServletMultipartResolver` on your behalf and is therefore able to resolve multipart requests "out of the box".

> Original answer

You should pass the additional data using the FormData object too.

Change your client-side code to append the additional data:

```
myApp.controller('passJSONTestController', function ($rootScope, $scope, MyService) {
     $scope.submitdata=function(){
        $scope.myJSONData = [
            {   'name':$scope.name,
                'sinNumber': $scope.sinNo,
                'status': $scope.status,
                'message':$scope.message,
            }
        ];
        var fd=new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
            console.log("file " + file);
            fd.append('file',file);
        });

        // do this instead
        data.append('json', JSON.stringify($scope.myJSONData);
        ...
```

In your controller fix the request mapping and make it accept `MultipartHttpServletRequest` parameter instead of `List<MultipartFile>`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dataStack")
public class GetData {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllDataInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String sendInfo(MultipartHttpServletRequest req){        

       List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList = req.getFiles("file");
       ...

       String[] json = req.getParameterMap().get("json");

       // Jackson deserialization...but you could use any...Gson, etc
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       TypeReference<Map<String,String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String,String>>() {};
       Map<String,String> data = mapper.readValue(json[0], typeRef);
       ...
```

Make sure you update MyService to post to the new request mapping:

```
myService.sendJSON = function (fd) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         var myUrl = applnURL + '/dataStack/getAllDataInfo.form';
        ...
```

I think that should do it for you.

HTH

Comment: I was trying as you suggested, but it is not supporting getParameterMap - It says cannot resolve method getParameterMap..

Comment: I had modified MyService as :  $http.post(repUrl, formData, {  transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {   return data;
              }, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,  }}).then(function (response) {
          console.log("response " + response);  }, and ow it is hitting the spring controller but the multiPartFileList size is zero in spring controller. i.e.,List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList = req.getFiles("file"); //size is zero, files information is not present. Any inputs would be helpful..

Comment: @Paul Warren - I was trying above code  with spring and angularjs and as user nan mentioned, the multiPartFileList  size in spring controller is zero. Do we need to include any special headers while passing the request and in spring controller?

Comment: @user3684675 please see my updated answer.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @PaulWarren- Thanks for the update..i have tried as you suggested above but still unable to get the attached files details in the spring controller. I have added my complete updated code in the edited version of my post above(---EDITED (Updated code)-----). Any inputs would be helpful..I'm badly stuck at this..I am using spring4 (spring mvc) with angularjs.

Comment: @PaulWarren - I tried as you suggested in the answer you had updated on  06/22/2018, but the result is same as before, I could not able to get the list of files attached to the spring controller, the size of files in spring controller is zero. Any inputs on this would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Paul Warren  - Any inputs on the above issue would be helpful.thanks

Comment: Do you get any exceptions in the app server logs, or anything like that @nan?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your client code i.e. **MyService.js** send the correct Content-Type, which in your case is application/json

   ```
   headers : {
       'Content-Type': application/json
   }
   ```
2. On the server side i.e. **spring controller:**, make your request mapper aware of the datatype of incoming request by:

   `@RequestMapping(value = "/{myJSONData}/getAllDataInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: I need to pass the files information as well as JSON object to the spring controller. To pass the files information i need to set  headers : {   'Content-Type': undefined } in MyService.js and as you said to send json object the header should be application/json but it will not allow the files to send..Any inputs on how can i send files information as well as JSON object to the spring controller. I can convert the json to string and send as PathVariable but issue is when the object is too long or if it is including special characters it does not allow to send as PathVariable..

Comment: @PaulWarren - The file size in spring controller is zero, multiPartFileList in spring controller is zero, do i need to include any header information in spring controller to pass files information from angular to spring controller, please advice..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send in a form of Object(DTO)

Like below

```
var createEvaluationRequestObject = {"test":"Value1","test2":"value2"};
var createEvaluationRequest       = JSON.stringify (createEvaluationRequestObject);
```

try this, it should work

Comment: I can send by converting JSON>Stringify but issue is my JSON object can be too long with special characters involved in it.So it is not allowing me to send as a PathVariable. When the JSON has no special characters i could able to successfully send it to spring controller as a String. But in my case it might include many special characters and the value in the JSON can be long.Can i send files information and JSON object as RequestParam and RequestBody..